# Add all chars of a string to a list but merge numbers to one entry C#

Tags: c#

You have given a string like "(32+5)*20" and you need to create a list with all chars, but need to merge the numbers to one entry like "32" and "20". How to do it?

I have already tried

```
string formel = "(32+5)*20";

char[] zeichen = formel.ToCharArray();
var liste = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < zeichen.Length ; i++)
{
    if(Char.IsNumber(zeichen[i]) && formel.Substring(i, i + 1).Any(char.IsNumber))
    {
        liste.Add(zeichen[i].ToString() + zeichen[i+1].ToString());
    }
    else                
    {
        liste.Add(zeichen[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `merge`? Concatenate? Add? What do you expect the result to look like? Or is the actual question how to parse this string and perform the operations?

Comment: ```var list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("(");
            list.Add("32");
            list.Add("+");
            list.Add("5");
            list.Add(")");
            list.Add("*");
            list.Add("20");```

Comment: You mean `new List<string>{ "(", "32","+","5",")","*","20"}`. This isn't merging, this is a list of individual tokens. Please update the question and post the expected result because you can see that people are getting confused by the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, I got confused and wasted some time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list as posted will still contain the same number of elements as the string did, since you added to it on every loop iteration. To "merge" into one entry, you need to not add on some iterations, but instead add that digit to the previous number.

This is easier if you check if the previous item was a number, rather than the next.

```
for (int i = 0; i < zeichen.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && Char.IsNumber(zeichen[i]) && Char.IsNumber(zeichen[i - 1])) // if got a number, and had a number before
    {
        // Then dont Add to the list, instead add to the number/string
        liste[list.Count - 1] += zeichen[i];
        //liste.Add(zeichen[i].ToString() + zeichen[i + 1].ToString());
    }
    else
        liste.Add(zeichen[i].ToString());
}
// "(", "32", "+", "5", ")", "*", "20"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer I searched for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex to return the groups of numbers:

```
var formel = "(32+5)*20";
var pattern = "([0-9]+)";
var match = Regex.Match(formel, pattern);
```

and then use

```
match.Groups
```

Comment: I think he wants to match the other single characters? `"([0-9]+|.)"`?

Comment: @FireLancer or get all tokens? The question asks for one thing, the comment contains a very different desired output

Comment: Yeah this has to be a regex task - match the digits then you can just make the remaining characters into a list

Comment: The OP isn't asking for the digits though. The desired output in the comments contains all tokens

Comment: Question sounded to me like he wanted 32, 5, 20 returned. OP, please clarify

Comment: It is not really clear, I just went by the source code posted and where it seemed wrong. I think regex is a good solution, but maybe just provide both outputs/patterns for completeness?

Comment: @Fire Lancer I checked your code. The output is what I wanted. Can you also calculate with the outputs by using the right syntax? And how?

Comment: @Janic - please create a new question for this

Comment: Not simply/directly from the list because of brackets and I guess you would also want operator precedence. There are a few questions of stackoverflow as well as other resources you might refer to.

Comment: @Janic I didn't downvote but the question isn't clear. There's *still* no desired output in the question itself and the description asks for something completely different.

Comment: @Janic You should be able to edit/update the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Regex and LINQ

```
var dateText = "(32 + 5) * 20";
string splitPattern = @"[^\d]";
var  result = Regex.Split(dateText, splitPattern).Where(x=>x!="");
```

I hope this will help you @Janic

Comment: @janic , You will get a list of no in "result" variable.